# Spring REST XML service not accepting XML as "accept" header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have several REST services defined that are currently returning JSON formatted objects as service response bodies. I'm trying to make this service also accept XML as a new requirement though it does not accept this.

I'm following the [spring-mvc-showcase sample project](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase.git) and have setup my `pom.xml` dependencies almost identically, my service definitions likewise are very simple.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "api/sales/*")
public class SalesController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/countries", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<NamedEntity> getCountries() {
```

`NamedEntity` has the appropriate `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

Could somebody explain the most basic requirements that I would need to get XML as a `ResponseBody` that the [spring-mvc-showcase sample project](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase.git) is using.

**EDIT**: Added spring MVC sample.

The sample from the spring-mvc-showcase is as follows:

```
package org.springframework.samples.mvc.messageconverters;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("messageconverters/*")
public class MessageConvertersController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/xml", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody JavaBean writeXml() {
        return new JavaBean("bar", "fruit");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Check the request header, client needs to have "application/xml" in the header, rather than "application/json "

Having said this make sure you have registered appropriate message converter for your object. If you are using Java 6 then Spring will auto detect JAXB in your classpath or else you can manually add the converter.

Comment: Client does have the correct accepts clause `application/application+xml`, I was using JDK7 but have refactored and have switched back to JDK6 but still not working. I have also added jaxb to my POM with no luck, my curl call line is ` curl -H "Accept: application/application+xml" -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/fsweb/app/api/sales/countries'` which using the same `Accept` works for the spring sample project fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add @Produces("application/xml") to getCountries()

Comment: This does not seem to work, the samples mentioned do not also have this annotation, I'll update my post to show the sample controller from spring.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send "application/xml", not "application/application+xml". Also consider using:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/countries", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json", "application/xml"})
```

This ensures your method responds to those media types only and rejects others with 406 HTTP status code.

Answer (score 0):

try this dispatcher servlet config.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven
        content-negotiation-manager="contentManager" />

<bean id="contentManager"
        class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false" />
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
        <property name="useJaf" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

and some dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
```